# Archiving unarchiving in ios, how to handle errors?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a business object that I need to change one of its properties. I try to get a string representation of that prperty and then modify it, like I am trying in the following code

```
  NSMutableString *mutatingString = [ [ NSMutableString alloc ] init ] ;
  mutatingString = ( NSMutableString * ) [ businessOject valueForKey:@"basicproperty" ] ;
  [ mutatingString appendString:@"Modified" ];
```

How ever when I hot the third line where I appendString, I get the following exception :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
   'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not cast the result of  [ businessOject valueForKey:@"basicproperty" ] from NSString* to NSMutableString*.

```
NSString* str  =   [businessOject valueForKey:@"basicproperty" ];
NSMutableString *mutatingString = [[NSMutableString alloc ] initWithString:str  ] ;
[mutatingString appendString:@"Modified" ];
[businessOject setValue:mutatingString forKey:@"basicproperty" ]
```

Comment: More specifically, casting is not conversion.

Comment: Yeah, please forgive my silly mistake. It is a pointer cast. :P